# IP address representation in the Maxmind Geolitecity database

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address

I have the Maxmind Geolitecity database in a Mysql database.

I could see field like `startIpNum` and `endIpNum`.

The values for those fields are like this: 16777216 for `startIpNum` and `16777471`for endIpNum`.

My ip is 115.184.126.186, how can I convert my ip to match the `startIpNum` or `endIpNum`?

Answer (score 2):

Either use inet_aton() as suggested by lmz, or do it in php using:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

Note that this function returns an signed integer, meaning ranging from − 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, and I think the maxmind geoip database uses unsigned ints (0-4,294,967,295?) so you need to add 2,147,483,647 to it (2^31-1)

Comment: I'm pritty sure that you can use sprintf("%u", $ip2long($ip)) to get unsigned representation of long int in PHP.

Comment: Probably, and works if you want a string representation (which would be the case in SQL concatenation).

Answer (score 1):

Try the `inet_aton` function in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
<?php 
 $ipadd="115.184.126.186";
 $ips = explode(".",$ipadd);
 $x=($ips[3] + $ips[2] * 256 + $ips[1] * 256 * 256 + $ips[0] * 256 * 256 * 256);
 echo $x;
?>
```

just modify this one into a function..

[here](http://codepad.org/28gKYDgP) is the result of the code

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it like this-

`SELECT INET_ATON("115.184.126.186");`