# IP address long format: Who invented it? Is it internationally standardised?

Tags: ip, ip-address

According to this question [IP address representation in the Maxmind Geolitecity database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608120/ip-address-representation-in-the-maxmind-geolitecity-database)

What is the official name for this format of an ip-address? 
Who invented it? Is it internationally standardised?

I mean the format without dots. Never heard of it. I know about the binary octets separated by dots.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a decimal representation. IP address is a 32bit binary number which we usually represent in the dot-decimal notation you mentioned. Since it is originally an 32bit number it is easier (and faster) to store and manipulate it in it's native format (as a number) than to parse the string representation.

For example you have `10.0.0.1` address whose octets in binary looks like:

```
00001010.00000000.00000000.00000001
```

When you lose the dots and look at it like a number you get `167772161` which is what `ip2long()` function will return if you pass `10.0.0.1` as an argument.

Comment: No, it is a dotted-decimal representation

Comment: The difference is that in decimal you represent the whole IP as a number, in dotted-decimal you represent each octet as a number separated by dots.